# How to compute this limit superior?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $k,l\in \mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,...\}$ and $\varepsilon >0$.

Consider
$$
\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{m=0}^n \begin{pmatrix}n\\m\end{pmatrix}\left([\frac{1}{\varepsilon}l^mk^{n-m}]-1\right)=(*),
$$
where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$.

Now, I have to compute that
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log (*)=\log\frac{k+l}{2}
$$

and I have no idea how to do that.

The first thing I use is that $\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m}=2^n$, hence $(*)$ becomes
$$
(*)=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n}{m}\left[\frac{1}{\varepsilon}l^mk^{n-m}\right]-1\\=\frac{1}{2^n}\left(\binom{n}{0}\left[\frac{1}{\varepsilon}k^n\right]+\binom{n}{1}\left[\frac{1}{\varepsilon}lk^{n-1}\right]+\ldots \binom{n}{n}\left[\frac{1}{\varepsilon}l^n\right]\right)-1
$$

Comment: Now write $\lfloor x\rfloor = x - \lbrace x\rbrace$, where $\lbrace x\rbrace$ is the fractional part of $x$, so $0 \leqslant \lbrace x\rbrace < 1$.

Comment: Ok, I am not sure what is the benefit from doing this, but then I get $\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n}{m}\frac{l^mk^{n-m}}{\varepsilon}-\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n}{m}\left\{\frac{l^mk^{n-m}}{\varepsilon}\right\}$.

Comment: The first term should look familiar (pull out the $\varepsilon$ to see better). The second sum can easily be bounded by the properties of $\{\,\cdot\,\}$.

Comment: Okay, the first sum equals $(k+l)^n$ and the second sum is $\geq 0$ and $<1$. ?

Comment: Correct (modulo the factor $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$). So what bounds do you get for $(\ast)$ overall?

Comment: I think, $\frac{1}{2^n\varepsilon}(k+l)^n-1\leq (*)\leq \frac{1}{2^n\varepsilon}(k+l)^n$. Now taking the logarithm on both sides and dividing by n, we have the result. Okay. :D

Comment: You forgot the $-1$ that you isolated. Doesn't make much of a difference, but the bounds become $E - 2 \leqslant (\ast) \leqslant E - 1$.